How do I remove everything behind each @ in a string as long as it does not contain a / in sed?
In sed, how do I remove everything behind each @ in a string, as long as that does not contain a /?
i.e.
user@host becomes host
user:password@host becomes host
user:passw@rd@host becomes host
host:/foo@bar becomes foo@bar
host://foo@bar becomes foo@bar
user:password@host:/foo@bar becomes foo@bar


Is sed a requirement or other tool would be fine ? And could you add a test case if there is multiple / ?

awk would work too-- just any built in tool that will be available to me in a bash script.

Please show us your attempt - How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

When you say "behind", I think you mean "before" given your example.

Using sed :
sed 's/.*\///;t;s/.*@//' input


s - s/regexp/replacement/
.*\/ anything and then /
t from sed man page :


If  a s/// has done a successful substitution since the last input line was read and since the last t or T command, then branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.


.*@ anything and then @

Using perl :
perl -i.bak -pe '!/\// && s/.*@// || s/.*\///' input

